# I'm having a problem adapting an old module for sopel to run in discord with python 3.7

Tags: python, discord, python-asyncio

I've been working on migrating a python 3.2 module to 3.7 so that I can carry my Sopel bot over to Discord.  The current problem I'm having is with a `RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread` error in my `setup(bot)` function.

I've tried creating an `asyncio` loop inside the function, that however only iterated through the channel connections, and didn't do much else.  I know that I'm missing something obvious, but none of my research for the last few days has really seemed to solve it.  As this isn't my code, and I'm still a pretty new python person, some of it doesn't really seem to map to me, thus my inability to fix it.

Here's the code:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#pylint: disable = C0103, C0116, C0115, C0114, R0903

from __future__ import (
    unicode_literals,
    absolute_import,
    division,
    print_function
)

import asyncio
import threading
import re

from sopel import module
from sopel.config.types import (
    StaticSection, ValidatedAttribute, BaseValidated, NO_DEFAULT
)
from sopel.tools import get_input

import discord

import requests
from requests.exceptions import HTTPError

discord_api_url = 'https://discordapp.com/api'
client = discord.Client()


valid_message_pattern = r'^(?![.!?]\s*\w+)'


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged into Discord as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('----')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    content = message.clean_content
    if message.channel.id in client.channel_mappings \
            and not message.author.bot \
            and re.match(valid_message_pattern, content):
        irc_channel = client.channel_mappings[message.channel.id]
        content = re.sub(r'<(:\w+:)\d+>', r'\1', content)
        if message.attachments:
            extra = []
            if content:
                extra.append(content)
            for attachment in message.attachments:
                extra.append(attachment.get('url'))
            content = ' '.join(extra)
        content = content.replace('\n', ' ').strip()
        if content:
            if re.match(r'^_.+_$', content) and not message.attachments:
                # Discord uses markdown italics to denote /me action messages
                irc_message = '{} {}'.format(
                    message.author.name,
                    content[1:-1]
                )
                client.irc_bot.action(irc_message, irc_channel)
            else:
                irc_message = '<{}> {}'.format(message.author.name, content)
                client.irc_bot.msg(irc_channel, irc_message)

class DictAttribute(BaseValidated):
    '''Config attribute containing a list of key: value pairs.
    Key: value pairs are saved to the file as a comma-separated list.
    The spaces before and after each item are stripped.
    '''
    def __init__(self, name, default=None):
        default = default or {}
        super(DictAttribute, self).__init__(name, default=default)

    def parse(self, value):
        pairs = value.split(',')
        value = {}
        for item in pairs:
            k, v = item.split(':')
            value[k.strip()] = v.strip()
        return value

    def serialize(self, value):
        if not isinstance(value, dict):
            raise ValueError('DictAttribute value must be a dict')
        return ','.join(['{}:{}'.format(k, v) for k, v in value.items()])

    def configure(self, prompt, default, parent, section_name):
        each_prompt = '?'
        if isinstance(prompt, tuple):
            each_prompt = prompt[1]
            prompt = prompt[0]

            if default is not NO_DEFAULT:
                prompt = '{} [{}]'.format(prompt, default)
            else:
                default = ''
            values = []
            value = get_input(each_prompt + ' ') or default
            while value:
                values.append(value)
                value = get_input(each_prompt + ' ')
            return self.parse(','.join(values))


class DiscordSection(StaticSection):
    discord_token = ValidatedAttribute('discord_token')
    channel_mappings = DictAttribute('channel_mappings')


def _setup_webhooks(bot):
    bot.memory['webhooks'] = {}
    headers = {
        'Authorization': 'Bot {}'.format(bot.config.discord.discord_token)
    }
    for k, channel_id in bot.memory['channel_mappings'].items():
        try:
            r = requests.get(
                '{}/channels/{}/webhooks'.format(discord_api_url, channel_id),
                headers=headers
            )
            bot.memory['webhooks'][channel_id] = {}
            r.raise_for_status()
            for hook in r.json():
                if hook['name'] == 'discord-irc':
                    bot.memory['webhooks'][channel_id] = hook
            if not bot.memory['webhooks'][channel_id]:
                payload = {'name': 'discord-irc'}
                r = requests.post(
                    '{}/channels/{}/webhooks'.format(
                        discord_api_url,
                        channel_id
                    ),
                    headers=headers,
                    json=payload
                )
                r.raise_for_status()
                bot.memory['webhooks'][channel_id] = r.json()
        except HTTPError as e:
            print('Could not access webhook API for channel {}.'.format(
                channel_id))
            print('Make sure the bot user has the "Manage webhooks" permission'
                  'on the specified discord channel.')
            print(e)


def configure(config):
    config.define_section('discord', DiscordSection)
    config.discord.configure_setting(
        'discord_token',
        'Discord token for the app bot user'
    )
    config.discord.configure_setting(
        'channel_mappings',
        ('Comma-separated list of Discord channel to IRC channel mappings'
         ' (ex: #discord-channel1: #irc-channel1,'
         ' #discord-channel2: #irc-channel2)')
    )


def setup(bot):
    bot.config.define_section('discord', DiscordSection)
    client.irc_bot = bot
    client.channel_mappings = bot.config.discord.channel_mappings
    print(client.channel_mappings)
    # config order maps discord: IRC, invert the map for the IRC bot
    bot.memory['channel_mappings'] = {
        v: k for k, v in client.channel_mappings.items()
    }
    _setup_webhooks(bot)
    # only start the asyncio thread once (the discord thread can survive sopel
    # restarts)
    if not asyncio.get_event_loop().is_running():
        targs = (bot.config.discord.discord_token,)
        t = threading.Thread(target=client.run, args=targs)
        t.start()

# Match all messages except for those which start with common bot command
# prefixes
@module.require_chanmsg
@module.rule(valid_message_pattern)
def irc_message(bot, trigger):
    if not trigger.is_privmsg \
            and trigger.sender in bot.memory['channel_mappings']:
        discord_channel = bot.memory['channel_mappings'][trigger.sender]
        hook = bot.memory['webhooks'].get(discord_channel, {})
        if hook:
            headers = {
                'Authorization': 'Bot {}'.format(
                    bot.config.discord.discord_token)
            }
            content = trigger.match.string
            if trigger.tags.get('intent') == 'ACTION':
                content = '_{}_'.format(content)
            payload = {
                'content': content,
                'username': '{} (IRC)'.format(trigger.nick),
            }
            try:
                r = requests.post('{}/webhooks/{}/{}'.format(
                    discord_api_url, hook['id'], hook['token']
                    ),
                                  headers=headers,
                                  json=payload,
                                  )
                r.raise_for_status()
            except HTTPError as e:
                pass
```

Editing to add the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 92, in add_signal_handler
    signal.set_wakeup_fd(self._csock.fileno())
ValueError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/junya/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 614, in run
    loop.add_signal_handler(signal.SIGINT, lambda: loop.stop())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/asyncio/unix_events.py", line 94, in add_signal_handler
    raise RuntimeError(str(exc))
RuntimeError: set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread
```

Comment: A backtrace might be useful; your code doesn't call set_wakeup_fd at all.

Comment: Right, I knew I forgot something.  It's in the main post now.

Comment: You're trying to run the discord bot in a background thread, and it doesn't like that. Why are you doing that and where is `setup(bot)` called from?

Comment: It's called as a plugin to the sopel bot program.  That's where I feel I'm getting slightly confused.  Sopel's API allows a generic call to bot from the main program.

https://sopel.chat/docs/plugin.html

As far as the backgrounded thread part, I want the message receive functions to be multithreaded so that the bot can handle multiple requests at once.

Comment: Can you reverse the architecture? I mean, start all of sopel in a thread you've spawned, and spin up the discord main loop in the main thread.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, and can see, the bot spins up halfway, loads the plugins, and then finishes.  I am not positive there's a way to start the bot and then side load the plugins due to how the architecture is laid out.

Comment: As far as I can tell, discord is only invoking `add_signal_handler` for fancy handling of ^C. If you don't need that kind of thing, you could monkey-patch `add_signal_handler` on the event loop class so that it does nothing and just log that it was called. That would eliminate the error and let you decide whether you need the signal handling that the code attempts to set up. If you don't (which is quite likely), the rest should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up and started recoding from scratch.  Trying to tie the sopel bot into discord was too onerous, and I've already completed the rewrite.